# R10 boot timeout error deploying Angular 2 to Heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, angular

I'm trying to deploy my Angular 2 app to Heroku. It's building fine, and works fine on my local system, but I get this error:

```
2016-07-11T11:01:22.279789+00:00 app[web.1]: > TLBi@4.0.0 start /app
2016-07-11T11:01:29.109068+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] 
2016-07-11T11:01:29.109079+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > TLBi@4.0.0 lite /app
2016-07-11T11:01:29.187537+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > TLBi@4.0.0 tscw /app
2016-07-11T11:01:29.888677+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
2016-07-11T11:01:29.890117+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] ** browser-sync config **
2016-07-11T11:01:29.904639+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
2016-07-11T11:01:29.904641+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
2016-07-11T11:01:30.090493+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] Access URLs:
2016-07-11T11:01:30.090728+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  ---------------------------------------
2016-07-11T11:01:30.091252+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
2016-07-11T11:01:30.091731+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     External: http://172.17.133.154:3000
2016-07-11T11:01:30.093555+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  UI External: http://172.17.133.154:3001
2016-07-11T11:01:30.094251+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]  ---------------------------------------
2016-07-11T11:01:30.094919+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
2016-07-11T11:01:30.106268+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] Watching files...
2016-07-11T11:01:34.805688+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/classes/event.js
2016-07-11T11:01:34.818504+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/classes/helper.js
2016-07-11T11:01:34.883314+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/services/HerdService.js
2016-07-11T11:01:34.994936+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/services/ChartService.js
2016-07-11T11:01:34.995623+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/helpers/search.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.016882+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/components/groups.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.024795+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/components/Animal/pedigree-mini.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.039718+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/components/Animal/details.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.064949+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/components/app.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.080899+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/helpers/import.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.091307+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] [BS] File changed: js/services/AnimalService.js
2016-07-11T11:01:35.114542+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] 11:01:35 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
2016-07-11T11:02:20.833608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-07-11T11:02:20.833608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-07-11T11:02:21.723733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-11T11:02:21.704172+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with binding to a port, but I'm not sure where this is even configured in Angular 2 - I can't find any server files at all.

Thanks